# How to reset ckeditor save event

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

On a previous ajax call I get all articles for a selected Page.
Then I display them and bind this function - on click - to each of them. This is working only one time.
When I want to change a second or third article the article id inside the ajax call keeps holding its first value.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

function editArticle(article){
   // id changes for each article as it is supposed to
   var id = article.attr('data-id');
   var text = article.html();
   $('#ckModal').modal();
   $('.modal-title').text('Editing Article: '+id+' on Page: '+pageTitle);
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(text);
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.resize('100%', '350', true);
   CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('save', function(e){
      e.cancel();
    var html = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    if(html){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/admin/nodes/edit',
            cache: false,
            data: {'html' : html,
                    'articleId' : id }
        }).done(function(msg){
            // next two lines did not work
            //CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.fire('save');
            //CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.stop('save');

            // id stays the same
            console.log(id);

            // I echo an 'ok' string when update worked from php
            if(msg === 'ok'){
                article.html(html);
                $('#ckModal').modal('hide');

            }else{
                //alert(msg);
            }

        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + status + ' : ' + error);
        });
      }
  });
}
```

I had to cancel the save event to get and set Data and perform the ajax call.

But how do I restart or reset the 'save' event - if this is what is causing the problem. I am not so shure anymore ....

Comment: Not familiar with that specific  event but in general, canceling an event instance shouldn't affect it being used again. Personally i would use the form submit event to do the ajax

Comment: The Save Plugin is an addon and the save event is fired when clicking the disk symbol which automaticaly appears when textarea is wrap with a form tag. I did not want to use a additonal form button to send data when this functionality is already provided by the disk button.

Comment: that's fine but that event is also set up to submit form that editor is contained in. So save button gets clicked...form submit event would fire if you didn't use `cancel()`

Comment: so I might just have to submit the form after the ajax call !?

Comment: no... can prevent the default `submit` also in the submit handler using event.preventDefault() or return false. What exactly is the problem you currently have? There may well be protection in that plugin to prevent people submitting twice...I really don't know without getting into the documentation

Comment: the problem remains the same the article id is frozen to its first value after doing the first article update.

Comment: have you researched this in the plugin docs? Are any errors thrown?

Comment: yes I had a look and the save event fires the submit event thats true. So when i cancel save it should be all good. The problem is inside the ajax call, once initialized it keeps just the same id - no no errors thrown

Comment: sounds like `article.attr('data-id')` isn't being changed. I don't know how you are using this code

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by destroying editor instance in ajax done function and creating a new one after it.

```
function editArticle(article){
var id = article.attr('data-id');
var text = article.html();
//CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
$('#ckModal').modal();
$('.modal-title').text('Editing Article: '+id+' on Page: '+pageTitle);
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(text);
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.resize('100%', '350', true);
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('save', function(e){
    e.cancel();
    var html = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    if(html){
        var title = $('.modal-title').html()
        $('.modal-title').prepend(spinner);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/admin/nodes/edit',
            cache: false,
            data: {'html' : html,
                    'articleId' : id }
        }).done(function(msg){
            //console.log(id);
            $('.modal-title').html(title);
            if(msg === 'ok'){
                article.html(html);
                $('#ckModal').modal('hide');
                CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            }else{
                //alert(msg);
            }

        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + status + ' : ' + error);
        });
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning **multiple** event listeners on your editor instance 'editor1', one for each article. What happens is when you click save, the *first* listener (the first article assigned) called cancels all others with e.cancel().

I see you achieved what you wanted by destroying your editor. Doing this removes event listeners, and solves your problem. You could achieve the same with calling e.removeListener() in the handler, this way removing itself after the first run and avoiding the need to recreate the editor. Also note that destroying editors and recreating them is leaking memory (some versions worse than others [#13123](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13123), [#12307](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12307)), so one should probably avoid doing that if possible.

Both solutions make the save button unusable after a save; of course it will work after another article is chosen for editing. So my suggestion is to remove all previous listeners from your save command before assigning a new one, like this:

```
// ... in function editArticle ...
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.resize('100%', '350', true);
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getCommand('save').removeAllListeners();
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('save', function(e){
// ...
```